Getting Twilio caller's phone number in socket
I have an endpoint accepting requests from Twilio.
I am connecting it to a websocket where I handle the actual conversation.
To get context about the caller, I need the caller's phone number in the socket, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation. 
I also tried passing it as a query param:
@app.route('/call', methods=['POST'])
def call():
    """Accept a phone call."""
    response = VoiceResponse()
    connect = Connect()
    caller_number = request.form["From"]
    stream_url = f'wss://{request.host}/stream?caller_number={caller_number}'
    connect.stream(url=stream_url)
    response.append(connect)
    print(f'Stream URL: {stream_url}')  # Print the full URL to verify
    print(f'Incoming call from {caller_number}')
    return str(response), 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}

But it might have been removed somewhere along the way, since I do not get it in the websocket.
I also tried using the Parameter verb but it seems to be incompatible with the Connect verb.
How can I get the phone number in the websocket handler?
